# Tensorflow freeze_graph script failing on model defined with Keras

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to export a model built and trained with Keras to a protobuffer that I can load in a C++ script (as in this example). I've generated a .pb file containing the model definition and a .ckpt file containing the checkpoint data. However, when I try to merge them into a single file using the freeze_graph script I get the error:

```
ValueError: Fetch argument 'save/restore_all' of 'save/restore_all' cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. ("The name 'save/restore_all' refers to an Operation not in the graph.")
```

I'm saving the model like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model = nndetector.architecture.models.vgg19((3, 50, 50))
    model.load_weights('/srv/nn/weights/scratch-vgg19.h5')
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)
    graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
    tf.train.write_graph(graph_def=graph_def, logdir='.',   name='model.pb', as_text=False)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, 'model.ckpt')
```

nndetector.architecture.models.vgg19((3, 50, 50)) is simply a vgg19-like model defined in Keras.

I'm calling the freeze_graph script like this:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=[path-to-model.pb] --input_checkpoint=[path-to-model.ckpt] --output_graph=[output-path] --output_node_names=sigmoid --input_binary=True
```

If I run the `freeze_graph_test` script everything works fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Best regards

Philip

**EDIT**

I've tried printing `tf.train.Saver().as_saver_def().restore_op_name` which returns `save/restore_all`.

Additionally, I've tried a simple pure tensorflow example and still get the same error:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1), name='a')
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(2), name='b')
add = tf.add(a, b, 'sum')

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
tf.train.write_graph(graph_def=sess.graph.as_graph_def(), logdir='.',     name='simple_as_binary.pb', as_text=False)
tf.train.Saver().save(sess, 'simple.ckpt')
```

And I'm actually also unable to restore the graph in python. Using the following code throws `ValueError: No variables to save` if I execute it separately from saving the graph (that is, if I both save and restore the model in the same script, everything works fine).

```
with gfile.FastGFile('simple_as_binary.pb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, 'simple.ckpt')
```

I'm not sure if the two problems are related, or if I'm simply not restoring the model correctly in python.

Comment: how did you get the name of your output node?

Comment: You can either keep track of the name when you define the graph (taking into account scopes etc.), print the tensor when you create it, print all nodes in the graph (e.g. `for node in tf.get_default_graph().node: print node.name`), or inspect a graph def saved in text format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the order of these two lines in your original program:

```
tf.train.write_graph(graph_def=sess.graph.as_graph_def(), logdir='.',     name='simple_as_binary.pb', as_text=False)
tf.train.Saver().save(sess, 'simple.ckpt')
```

Calling `tf.train.Saver()` *adds* a set of nodes to the graph, including one called `"save/restore_all"`. However, this program calls it *after* writing out the graph, so the file you pass to `freeze_graph.py` doesn't contain those nodes, which are necessary for doing the rewriting.

Reversing the two lines should make the script work as intended:

```
tf.train.Saver().save(sess, 'simple.ckpt')
tf.train.write_graph(graph_def=sess.graph.as_graph_def(), logdir='.',     name='simple_as_binary.pb', as_text=False)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh.... This makes sense. I should've figured that out myself, I actually did notice that the graph had additional nodes after initializing Saver.

I just tested it, and it seems to work. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

So, I got it working. Sort of.

By using `tensorflow.python.client.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` directly instead of first saving `GraphDef` and a checkpoint to disk and then using the `freeze_graph` tool/script, I have been able to save a `GraphDef` containing both graph definition and variables converted to constants.

**EDIT**

mrry updated his answer, which solved my issue of freeze_graph not working, but I'll leave this answer as well, in case anyone else could find it useful.